# How can i secured my url link in htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I want to secured my website from sql injection code executing in url 
Like:

```
www.website.com'
www.website.com order
www.website.com order by
www.website.com --
```

can i create my custom error in .htaccess in which: if visitor insert above keyword in url,page will be redirect to error.html.
anyother suggestion will be appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

```
RewriteRule [^a-zA-Z0-9/] /error.html [L]
```

But finding out the right `regex` to block SQL injection only through `htaccess` will be quiet a challenge... Such a restrictive rule like `[a-zA-Z0-9/]` may block legitimate queries.

Plus it only checks the URI: `POST`, `GET` and `COOKIE` are three other means of SQL injection.